# JR report doesn't show data

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have written this code to show a simple report using *iReport 4.7.1*.

```java
  private void printReport() {
    try {
        JRTableModelDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(
                new JTable().getModel());

        String reportSource = "C:\\Reports\\report1.jrxml";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        params.put("Name", "SriLanka");

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here are my libraries:

- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
- commons-digester-2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- jasperrreports-4.7.1.jar
- jasperreports-applet-4.7.1.jar
- jasperreports-javaflow-4.7.1.jar
- groovy-all-1.7.5.jar

and *NetBeans* output shows this warning

> Oct 08, 2012 2:57:31 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.component.ComponentsEnvironment findBundles
>   WARNING: Found two components for namespace http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components

and here is the *.jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="BlankPage" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5174594e-de3c-4b09-932b-c6665bf6a34b">
    <parameter name="Name" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="fd02a8bc-548b-41c1-aed5-2a7c2e257704" x="210" y="23" width="157" height="36"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The report opens but doesn't show any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you should:

1. check your datasource, it can be empty;
2. add *textFields* elements with fields expressions (*`<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field}]]></textFieldExpression>`*) to the *Detail* band to show records in report.

Anyway your parameter ***Name*** should be displayed in the *Title* band (in generated report). You can pass even the ***JREmptyDataSource*** to check this.

---

For showing data you can chose one of this ways:

#### 1. Using *Detail* band

It is classical, "old school" method for showing data stored in records from the data source. The *JR* engine iterates through the data source for rendering this section. With help of *textField* elements we can show the fields values.

*The sample*: look at `$jasperreports$\demo\samples\jasper` sample from *JR* [distribution package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.7.0/jasperreports-4.7.0-project.zip/download).

#### 2. Using *Crosstab* component

The *Crosstab* component used for summarizing data into grid which has two dimensions.

The sample: look at `$jasperreports$\demo\samples\crosstabs` sample.

#### 3. Using *List* component

The *List* component iterates on set of its records (defined with help of ***subDataset*** property).

*The sample*: look at [Using the Built-in List Component sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/list/index.html#list).

#### 4. Using *Table* component

The *Table* is using for showing data with tabular structure. As a *List* component has its own ***subDataset***.

*The sample*: look at [Using the Built-in Table Component sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/table/index.html#table).

#### 4. Using *Subreport* component

The *Subreport* is using for building complex reports such as compilation of different reports in one. This component often operates with subqueries.

*The sample*: look at [Subreports sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#subreports).

---

You can read details in [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)